# Transform a parse tree of a polynomial to a parse tree of its evaluation according to Horner's scheme

Tags: algorithm, expression-trees, compiler-optimization, parse-tree, expression-templates

Could you please point me to an algorithm that takes a (binary) parse tree for evaluating a polynomial expression in a single variable and returns an equivalent parse tree that evaluates the polynomial according to Horner's rule.

The intended use case is in expression templates. The idea is that for a matrix `x` the parse tree obtained from

```
a + bx + c * x*x + d * x*x*x...
```

will get optimized into the corresponding parse tree of

```
a + x *( b + x( c + x*d))
```

Comment: Is the expression in [monomial basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_basis)?

Comment: @Shahbaz Not quite, because its available as a parse tree with + and * operations

Comment: Is the algorithm off-line? How efficient should it be?

Comment: @Shahbaz its essentially an optimization pass that will get amortized over several evaluations of the polynomial. So it neednt be very fast. Perhaps the way is to get to the monomial coefficients from the tree and then use the standard Horner's way.

Comment: I believe if you expand the expression to monomial, then applying horner's law would be trivial.

Comment: @Shahbaz Indeed. What I am looking for is there a series of tree to tree transformations that can be applied so that I get an optimized parse tree as a result. But maybe obtaining the monomial coefficients from the original tree is the way to go, though not the preferred solution, because this logic will need to encoded as an expression template.

Comment: I haven't thought about non monomial trees, but with those, a recursive algorithm can transform the tree. My feeling however is that, if you find the coefficients and reconstruct a tree according to Horner's law, it would be simpler.

Comment: @Shahbaz Given that the parse tree manipulation would be in the form of a C++ metaprogram I think recursion over the parse tree is the preferred way. But I agree without those restrictions, getting the desired tree via the monomial coefficients would be the simplest way. But in the current setup it gets messy. If you do have a recursion operating on the binary expression tree, I would be extremely interested.

Comment: I like both the answers, can the bounty be divided ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the [monomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_basis) of the tree by a recursive function. Converting these coefficients and getting an expression according to Horner's law would be [simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).

I can give you a simple recursive function that computes these values, even though a more efficient one *may* exist.

#### Theoretical stuff

First, let's formulate expressions. An expression `E`:

```
E = a0 + a1x + a2x^2 + ... + anx^n
```

can be written as an (n+1)-ary tuple:

```
(a0, a1, a2, ..., an)
```

Then, we define two operations:

- Addition: Given two expressions `E1 = (a0, ..., an)` and `E2 = (b0, ..., bm)`, the corresponding tuple of `E1 + E2` is:

  ```
            {(a0+b0, a1+b1, ..., am+bm, a(m+1), ..., an) (n > m)
  E1 + E2 = {(a0+b0, a1+b1, ..., an+bn, b(n+1), ..., bm) (n < m)
            {(a0+b0, a1+b1, ..., an+bn)                  (n = m)
  ```

  that is, there are `max(n,m)+1` elements, and the `i`<sup>th</sup> element is computed by (with a C-ish syntax):

  ```
  i<=n?ai:0 + i<=m?bi:0
  ```
- Multiplication: Given two expressions `E1 = (a0, ..., an)` and `E2 = (b0, ..., bm)`, the corresponding tuple of `E1 * E2` is:

  ```
  E1 * E2 = (a0*b0, a0*b1+a1*b0, a0*b2+a1*b1+a2*b0, ... , an*bm)
  ```

  that is, there are `n+m+1` elements, and the `i`<sup>th</sup> element is computed by

  ```
  sigma over {ar*bs | 0<=r<=n, 0<=s<=m, r+s=i}
  ```

The recursive function is therefore defined as follows:

```
tuple get_monomial_coef(node)
    if node == constant
        return (node.value)  // Note that this is a tuple
    if node == variable
        return (0, 1)        // the expression is E = x
    left_expr = get_monomial_coef(node.left)
    right_expr = get_monomial_coef(node.right)
    if node == +
        return add(left_expr, right_expr)
    if node == *
        return mul(left_expr, right_expr)
```

where

```
tuple add(tuple one, tuple other)
    n = one.size
    m = other.size
    for i = 0 to max(n, m)
        result[i] = i<=n?one[i]:0 + i<=m?other[i]:0
    return result

tuple mul(tuple one, tuple other)
    n = one.size
    m = other.size
    for i = 0 to n+m
        result[i] = 0
        for j=max(0,i-m) to min(i,n)
            result[i] += one[j]*other[i-j]
    return result
```

Note: in the implementation of `mul`, `j` should iterate from `0` to `i`, while the following conditions must also hold:

```
j <= n (because of one[j])
i-j <= m (because of other[i-j]) ==> j >= i-m
```

Therefore, `j` can go from `max(0,i-m)` and `min(i,n)` (which is equal to `n` since `n <= i`)

#### C++ implementation

Now that you have the pseudo-code, the implementation shouldn't be hard. For the tuple type, a simple `std::vector` would suffice. Therefore:

```
vector<double> add(const vector<double> &one, const vector<double> &other)
{
    size_t n = one.size() - 1;
    size_t m = other.size() - 1;
    vector<double> result((n>m?n:m) + 1);
    for (size_t i = 0, size = result.size(); i < size; ++i)
        result[i] = (i<=n?one[i]:0) + (i<=m?other[i]:0);
    return result;
}

vector<double> mul(const vector<double> &one, const vector<double> &other)
{
    size_t n = one.size() - 1;
    size_t m = other.size() - 1;
    vector<double> result(n + m + 1);
    for (size_t i = 0, size = n + m + 1; i < size; ++i)
    {
        result[i] = 0.0;
        for (size_t j = i>m?i-m:0; j <= n; ++j)
            result[i] += one[j]*other[i-j];
    }
    return result;
}

vector<double> get_monomial_coef(const Node &node)
{
    vector<double> result;
    if (node.type == CONSTANT)
    {
        result.push_back(node.value);
        return result;
    }
    if (node.type == VARIABLE)
    {
        result.push_back(0.0);
        result.push_back(1);  // be careful about floating point errors
                              // you might want to choose a better type than
                              // double for example a class that distinguishes
                              // between constants and variable coefficients
                              // and implement + and * for it
        return result;
    }
    vector<double> left_expr = get_monomial_coef(node.left);
    vector<double> right_expr = get_monomial_coef(node.right);
    if (node.type == PLUS)
        return add(left_expr, right_expr);
    if (node.type == MULTIPLY)
        return mul(left_expr, right_expr);
    // unknown node.type
}

vector<double> get_monomial_coef(const Tree &tree)
{
    return get_monomial_coef(tree.root);
}
```

Note: this code is untested. It may contain bugs or insufficient error checking. Make sure you understand it and implement it yourself, rather than copy-paste.

From here on, you just need to build an expression tree from the values this function gives you.

Comment: Yeah this idea should work, upvoted. I am holding off on acceptance for a while hoping for a solution that solves it directly without forming the monomial coefficient tuple.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following tranformation.

*Assumption*: the parse tree of the polynomial is in the order of increasing exponents -- if this assumption does not hold, the partial polynomes can be swapped around in the parse tree to make the assumption hold

*Assumption*: the parse tree holds exponential forms of the variable (e.g. `x^2`) instead of multiplicational forms (e.g. `x*x`), except for `x^0` -- simple transformations can convert between the two in either direction

*Assumption*: the coefficients (if constant) in the polynom are non-zero -- this is to avoid having to deal with (`a+0*x+c*x^2` -> `a+x(cx)` instead of `a+cx^2`)

Parse tree for `a+b*x^1+c*x^2+d*x^3`:

```
  .+..
 /    \
a   ...+....
   /        \
  *         .+..
 / \       /    \
b  ^      *      *
  / \    / \    / \
 x   1  c   ^  d   ^
           / \    / \
          x   2  x   3
```

Transformation to `a+x(b+c*x^1+d*x^2)`

```
  +
 / \
a   *
   / \
  x   +
     / \
    b   .+..
       /    \
      *      *
     / \    / \
    c   ^  d   ^
       / \    / \
      x   1  x   2
```

Transformation to `a+x(b+x(c+d*x^1))`

```
  +
 / \
a   *
   / \
  x   +
     / \
    b   *
       / \
      x   +
         / \
        c   *
           / \
          d   ^
             / \
            x   1
```

Then finally (`a+x(b+x(c+d*x))`):

```
  +
 / \
a   *
   / \
  x   +
     / \
    b   *
       / \
      x   +
         / \
        c   *
           / \
          d   x
```

The common transformation is:

```
 .            ->    .
  .           ->     .
   .          ->      .
    +         ->      .*..
   / \        ->     /    \
  *   N(k+1)  ->    ^      +
 / \          ->   / \    / \
ck  ^         ->  x   k  ck  N'(k+1)
   / \        -> 
  x   k       ->
```

where `N'(k+1)` is the same subtree as `N(k+1)` with each exponent `j` replaced with `j-k` (if `k` is 1, replace the `x^k` subtree with `x`)

The algorithm is then applied again(*) on `N'(k+1)` until its root is `*` (instead of `+`), indicating that the final partial polynom is reached.  If the final exponent is 1, replace the exponential part with `x` (`x^1` -> `x`)

(*) here is the recursion part

*Note*: if you keep track of the exponent changes in the `N(k+1)` subtrees cumulatively, you can put the last two steps together to transform `N(k+1)` recursively in one go

*Note*: If you want to allow negative exponents, then either

a) extract the highest negative exponent as the first term:

```
a*x^-2 + b*x^-1 + c + d*x + e*x^2  ->  x^-2(a+b*x+c*x^2+d*x^3+d*x^4)
```

and apply the above transformation

or b) separate the positive and negative exponential parts of the equation and appply the above transformation on each separately (you will need to "flip" the operands for the negative-exponent side and replace multiplication with division):

```
a*x^-2 + b*x^-1 + c + d*x + e*x^2  ->  [a+x^-2 + b*x-1] + [c + d*x + e*x^2] ->
-> [(a/x + b)/x] + [c+x(d+ex)]
```

this approach seems more complicated than a)

Comment: You put in a lot of work in the answer, hence tghe upvote but I am really looking at an expression tree made up of + and *

Comment: @san - If you refer to the occasional x^k in the expression tree, you can easily transform that to x*x*...*x at the end.  Of can you not deal with exponentials even in the mid-steps?

Comment: @san - the replace each `x^k` above with the corresponding `x*x*...*x` subtree and either a) calculate their number (getting `k`) or b) remove one `*x` after the other (and applying the above aglorithm with `x` for each one removed) until they are all gone

Comment: @san, didn't you say the tree is **not** in monomial form?

Comment: @Shahbaz It indeed isnt. I think what this solution is saying is similar to your solution, i.e. collapse the '*' till you get to the monomial form and then do the fairly standard manipulations.

Comment: On the contrary, this solution assumes the expression is already in monomial form, and directly converts the tree according to Horner's law.

Comment: @Shahbaz True. I was reading in between the lines, realizing it would be easy to merge the consecutive '*' to get to the `monomial' expression tree

Comment: @san - it is fairly easy to treat the expanded monomial (`x*x*...*x`) as if it _was_ a monomial, you just need to traverse that expanded form to calculate the exponent and then treat it as if it was a monomial

Comment: Attila: The problem is that the tree could be representing an expression such as this: `(1 + x^2) * (2*x + x + x^3 + 1*x + 2) * (3 * (x + x^2) + x * (x^2 + 3 * x^2))`

Comment: @Shahbaz - if it is, the question should be updated -- the example used suggests the polynom is in the canonical form (with exponentials expanded)

Comment: @Attila Read my conversation with him on the comments of his question

Comment: @Shahbaz To be honest I took "monomial" form to mean a linear combination of the monomial basis i.e. x^0, X^1, X^2.... and  not the expanded form 1, x, x*x though the latter works for my use case. Shahbaz's solution sketch is more general though.

Comment: Well, basically my solution just turns the expression to monomial form. You can then use attila's solution to convert it, or even better, directly use the [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method#Derivation) and create the final tree.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to apply the following rules until you can't apply them anymore.

```
((x*A)*B)     -> (x*(A*B))
((x*A)+(x*B)) -> (x*(A+B)))
(A+(n+B))     -> (n+(A+B))  if n is a number
```

where `A` and `B` are subtrees.

Here is an OCaml code to do this:

```
type poly = X | Num of int | Add of poly * poly | Mul of poly * poly

let rec horner = function
  | X -> X
  | Num n -> Num n
  | Add (X, X) -> Mul (X, Num 2)
  | Mul (X, p)
  | Mul (p, X) -> Mul (X, horner p)
  | Mul (p1, Mul (X, p2))
  | Mul (Mul (X, p1), p2) -> Mul (X, horner (Mul (p1, p2)))
  | Mul (p1, p2) -> Mul (horner p1, horner p2) (* This case should never be used *)
  | Add (Mul (X, p1), Mul (X, p2)) -> Mul (X, horner (Add (p1, p2)))
  | Add (X, Mul (X, p))
  | Add (Mul (X, p), X) -> Mul (X, Add (Num 1, horner p))
  | Add (Num n, p)
  | Add (p, Num n) -> Add (Num n, horner p)
  | Add (p1, Add (Num n, p2))
  | Add (Add (Num n, p1), p2) -> Add (Num n, horner (Add (p1, p2)))
  | Add (p1, p2) -> horner (Add (horner p1, horner p2))
```

Comment: This is really nice elegant and general. Do you know if its been proved anywhere that those three transformations are sufficient.